# Problems parsing XML file with javascript (limit results)

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, limit

I have the script listed at bottom that parse informations from XML file and run correctly. If I want to show a max limit results (for example 5), I'm not able to do it. I think "Slice" function is what I need. I have no problems to use the same function in a simple text array ("Mango, "Banana", "Kiwi", "Peach"). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");

function displayCDInfo(i)
{
  artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  country=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  company=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPANY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  price=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  txt="Artist: "+artist+"<br />Title: "+title+"<br />Year: "+year+"<br />Country: "+country+"<br />Company: "+company+"<br />Price: "+price  ;
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not cleare what really you want but i think you are calling this function somewhere and your var x is an array. Try this .

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    displayCDInfo(i)
    }
```

Comment: Your reply is what I needed. Thanks Rupesh!

Comment: @user1685609 If so accept the answer by clicking right sign at my answer :)